# Problem with Angular reportProgress in Chrome Browser

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome

I'm trying to implement like a ChatBot, an a Chat what you ask him a question and their reply you in streaming, word by word, but I'm stuck because in Chrome doesn't report me de Progress well, only show me the send event and the last chunk before the response, and the final response. The thing is that in Safari and Firefox works well or works like I want.

I tried to put a lot of Headers to try Chrome not wait until the last response, this is the Service:

```
createQuestion(question: any): any {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Content-Type-Options':'nosniff',
      //'Accept-Encoding': 'identity',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    });

   return this.http.post(this.chatbot, question, {
      headers,
      observe: 'events',
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'text' as 'json',
    });
}
```

And this is the function that I call to try to watch every event:

```
this.chatBotService.createQuestion(auxQuestion)
      .subscribe(
        {
          next:  (event: any) => {
            console.log(event)
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.Sent) {
              console.log('Solicitud enviada:', event);
            } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.ResponseHeader) {
              console.log('Encabezado de respuesta recibido:', event.headers);
            } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
              const httpProgressEvent = event as HttpEvent<any>;
              if (httpProgressEvent instanceof HttpResponse) {
                const data: string = httpProgressEvent.body as string;
                console.log('Datos en streaming:', data);
              }
            } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
              const connectionHeader = event.headers.get('Connection');
              console.log('Connection Header:', connectionHeader);
              console.log('Respuesta final recibida:', event);
            }
          },
          error: (error: any) => {
            console.error('Error en la solicitud:', error);
          }
        }

      );
```

Like I said in Firefox and Safari works well, image in Firefox with the operation that I want:
[Image of console.log in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPqiP.png)

And this is in Chrome:
[Image of console.log in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e83bq.png)

Thank you in advance.